# Rails – I want to change the status of my table by putting a certain time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I've only been in RoR for a short time.

I have a list table with a field: status(enabled, disabled) and end_date, I have my form where I put a certain end time.
I would like that when reaching this end time, the status field changes to disabled.
is there anything i can do to achieve this ?

```
create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer "user_id"
t.binary "uuid", limit: 36
t.string "name"
t.string "description"
t.datetime "end_date"
t.integer "status", default: 1
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_lists_on_user_id"
```

end

Comment: you can use a callback or do it programatically, where you change the status if the end_time meets the criteria you desire https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Comment: Make sure whether you actually need the `status` column in your database. If the status is strictly determined by the `end_date`, you could also infer the status from that, rather than storing it. Then, you could just add a simple method to your model, e.g. `def status; end_date ? end_date <= Time.now : true; end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method that checks if the end time is the same as current date and then set the status value

```
def self.update_status
  List.where(end_date: DateTime.current).update_all(status: 'disabled')
end
```

Now you can call this method from the scheduler to run this method every min, every hour, or every day as per your requirement.
Checkout [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem which is popular to write scheduled jobs.

```
every :hour do # Many shortcuts available: :hour, :day, :month, :year, :reboot 
  runner "List.update_status"
end
```